# Not able to see Add->Existing Project as Azure Web Job Option when I right click on Web project in Solution Explorer of Visual Studio 2017

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, continuous-deployment

When I right click on the Web Project in the Solution Explorer of Visual Studio 2017, I don't see an option 'Add Existing Project as Azure Web Job'. 
I did install Nuget-packages such as Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish for the web project.
I am following this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs#convertlink to enable automatic WebJobs deployment with a web project.

Ideally, I am supposed to see like this, but that highlighted option is not shown in my visual studio 2017
[Click to see image for how actually visual studio should have shown me an option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5n5zN.png)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I don't see an option 'Add Existing Project as Azure Web Job'.

As far as I know, Visual Studio does not support to deploy WebJobs with ***ASP.NET Core Web Application*** currently.

[image]

But this feature is available in ***ASP.NET Web Application***.

[image]

If you can not see *'Add Existing Project as Azure Web Job'* option in your ASP.NET Web Application, you can try to repair or reinstall your Visual Studio and upgrade/reinstall your [Azure SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/).

Comment: Sad...just spent 45 minutes repairing VS and still no "Add Existing Project as Azure Web Job" menu option.